# Controls disappears?How to fix?please?(use C# winform)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, controls, alphablending

I use Alpha Blended Windows (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20758/Alpha-Blended-Windows-Forms), But when dragging on the form
or when double click on the form, Cause controls to disappears or flash.
How to fix?please?Thank you

[Please see the gif of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgwzQ.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following field to true. (By default, options are set to false)

As per their documentation:

```
bool EnhancedRendering
```

> If true when the form is dragged, the foreground window will be drawn
>   to the background window and then hidden. This prevents any visual
>   disparity between the two forms.

```
this.EnhancedRendering = true;
```

Comment: I set EnhancedRendering to false, It's ok! Thank you very much for your tips. You were a great help to me!^_^